# Selenium get text from element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new in selenium and I want to get some data from the website.
So I have next HTML lines [image]

and I want to get data in the next representation "Some start /file.php/1757/chm_images/image089.gif some end."

Can anyone give me some advice, please?

I use c#, but if you have code in another language, it would be great too

Answer (score 0):

You really should post what you have tried. Your html markup needs some love. So if you had this, you could do the below. You should, at a minimum, wrap your text in a span tag.

```
<div class="qtext">
<span>some start</span>
<img src="/blah" alt="image">
<span>some end</span>
</div>

var text1 = driver.findElement(By(xpath("//div[@class='qtext'/span[1]")).Text;
var text2 = driver.findElement(By(xpath("//div[@class='qtext']/span[2]")).Text;
```

If you can't fix the markup....

```
var text1 = driver.findElement(By(xpath("//div[@class='qtext']/text()[1]")).Text;
var text2 = driver.findElement(By(xpath("//div[@class='qtext']/text()[2]")).Text;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my HTML, it some kind of university task and I can only parse HTML but not change it

Answer (score 0):

The part which you marked is a single text node which is not a `WebElement` so cannot be just fetched using xpath. What you can do is to use `JavascriptExecutor` to execute javascript that would return you required value.

For example you have the following html:

```html
<test>
  Hello
  <br/>
  World
</test>
```

You have two text nodes here. The first node is `//test/text()[1]` and the second one is `//test/text()[2]`.

So in order to fetch the first node you code do something like this:

```cs
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string helloText = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.evaluate(\"//test/text()[1]\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.cloneNode(true).text;");
```